# PHP form resets upon selection from a drop down

Tags: php, mysql, forms, dropdown

This php form populates the drop down selections with divisions and project codes that other php forms collect from the user via. My SQL. Those forms seem to be working. When I come to this specific form the last drop down (the code below) when you select the whole Form resets.

```
<?php
    echo'<select name = "pCode" id = "pCode" onchange = "document.form1.submit()">
    <option value="new">Please Select a Project Code</option>';
    $ress = $db->Exe_Qry("select * from pr_projects");
    while ($roww = $db->Next_Record($ress))
    {
        echo "<OPTION VALUE=".$roww["code"].">".$roww["code"]."</OPTION>";
    }
    echo'</select>';
?>
```

Any idea what is done wrong?

Also `OnSubmit` is there because when the drop down is selected, the form is suppose to retrieve the project description and another AP code (both in the mysql database) so If i remove the `OnSubmit` its not shown `"<td><?php echo $apcode;?> </td>"` this is the code for displaying after the dropbox selection

The same for has another dropbox which has the same functionality it's working fine. So I followed the same steps with the other! Code for the dropbox is as such

```
<select name="budCode" id = "budCode"  onChange="document.form1.submit()">
<?php 
    echo'<option value="new">Please Select a budget Code</option>';
    $empno = $_SESSION['proclogin_un'];
    $ress = $db->Exe_Qry("select bud_code from pc_bud_req_user where user=$empno");
    while ($roww = $db->Next_Record($ress))
    {
        echo "<OPTION VALUE=".$roww["bud_code"].">".$roww["bud_code"]."</OPTION>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: because your submiting the form on change of select box

Comment: It's because of your `onchange` attribute on select: you submit the form with each option change. Removing it should work.

Comment: Hi again, i forgot to add this bit to the question, on submit is there because when the drop down is selected, the form is suppose to retrieve the project description and another AP code (both in the mysql database) so If i remove the onsubmit its not shown.   
" <td><?php echo $apcode;?> </td>" heres the the code for the that which is supposed to generate

Comment: If every option give you a different APCode, you have to use AJAX to retrieve them onchange of the select

Comment: The same form has another dropbox that has the same functionality. I thought if i followed its steps it should be fine. The code for that is

Answer (score 0):

Because your submiting the form on change of select box

```
onchange = "document.form1.submit()"
```

Remove this one it will work .

Comment: Hi again, i forgot to add this bit to the question, on submit is there because when the drop down is selected, the form is suppose to retrieve the project description and another AP code (both in the mysql database) so If i remove the onsubmit its not shown

Comment: " <td><?php echo $apcode;?> </td>" heres the the code for the that

Comment: if you want keep those form values means you have one way 1) on change of select box call ajax and get the apcode without page load .